# How to cover `this` in controller functions?

Tags: angularjs, flowtype

```
function Controller () {
  this.foo = 'bar'
}

angular.module('app')
.controller('ctrl', Controller)
```

In this snippet, `flow coverage` complains about not knowing the value of `this`.

flow can't infer that angularjs internally uses the Controller function as a constructor, in pseudo-code: `new Controller()`

Could an annotation be added to indicate that the Controller function will be invoked with the `new` operator?

I tried to explicitly return `this` (as a potential hint) with no success.

Comment: You can use controller as syntax for achieving this

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSDoc.

```js
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Controller() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}
```